# Doubts on multiplication of square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\sqrt{1-(1-2x)} \times \sqrt{1-2x} $

Can I just multiply the terms ignoring the square root ?

Eg. When I do that I get -

$\sqrt{2x(1-2x)} $

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. There is a rule that says $\sqrt a\times \sqrt b = \sqrt{ab}$, as long as $a$ and $b$ are non-negative, and that is exactly what that rule says: To find the product of two square roots, take the product of the things inside the square roots, and then put the square root on top. Of course, the rule may be used the other way too, to *split* a single square root into two. For instance, $\sqrt{12} =\sqrt{4\times 3} = \sqrt4\times\sqrt3$, which then simplifies to $2\sqrt3$.

Caution: This only applies when the operation in question is a multiplication (or division). It does *not* work with addition or subtraction.

Also, when there are $x$'s involved, you need to be careful to make sure that $x$ is restricted so that whatever's inside any of the square roots never becomes negative. Specifically, in your case, that means that $x$ must be greater than or equal to $0$ (because that's what makes $1-(1-2x)$ non-negative) and at the same time it must be less than or equal to $\frac12$ (because that's what makes $1-2x$ non-negative).

Comment: Are you saying that $\sqrt 1=\sqrt{(-1)\cdot(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1}=i\cdot i=-1$, though?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I was a bit quick there. Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I understand now

Comment: It actually works unless both are negative: for $a,b \ge 0$, $\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$ and $\sqrt{-a} \sqrt{b} = i \sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{(-a)b}$, and furthermore $\sqrt{-a} \sqrt{-b} = -\sqrt{ab} = -\sqrt{(-a)(-b)}$

Comment: @Blrp : ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ No: ​ ​ ​ Let $z$ be a non-trivial cube-root of $1$. ​ $\left(\hspace{-0.03 in}\sqrt{z}\right)^3 = -1 \neq 1 = \sqrt1 = \sqrt{z^{\hspace{.03 in}3}}$ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer It was pretty clear from the context that I was only talking about square roots of real numbers. If you wanna nitpick you could point out that Arthur doesn't specify non-negative _real_ numbers, so your counterexample works there too.

Comment: @Blrp I agree with the first point of your last comment. However, positive and negative makes _no sense_ for complex numbers, so his counterexample doesn't work on my answer. Also, your counterexample doesn't work because $\sqrt a$ is _undefined_ for negative $a$. Writing $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is _at best_ a reminder, and a poor one at that. It's much better to write $i^2=-1$. Yes, complex numbers have square roots, but it is incorrect to use $\sqrt{\hphantom a\vphantom a}$ to denote then.

Comment: @Arthur My point was that if you interpret nonnegative as simply "number that doesn't belong to $\mathbb{R}^-$ and don't specify nonnegative _real_ number, then you could say that nonreal numbers are all nonnegative. Not saying this is a valid objection; just a pointless nitpick, which was exactly my point. What do you mean by "my counterexample"? I didn't try to counter anything. Also, square roots are defined for whatever we choose to define them for, and what you're doing is also pointless nitpicking. (1/4)

Comment: If anything the more objective answer is that $\sqrt{a}$ for negative $a$ is indeed defined, since there's no ambiguity and everyone understands what it means. Principal square root of nonreal numbers is typically defined as $\sqrt{r e^{i\phi}} = \sqrt{r} e^{i\phi/2}$ for $r > 0, \phi \in (-\pi, \pi]$. You don't need to agree with this definition or indeed have any definition at all, but there's nothing wrong with it. Furthermore, complaining about the definition $i = \sqrt{-1}$ is silly; it's just as valid as $i^2 = -1$ if not more. (2/4)

Comment: The common complaint is that you can't define $i$ by the square root of a negative number because negative numbers don't have square roots before we define $i$. In other words, we can't define $i$ by using the operation $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ with negative numbers because we need to introduce $i$ before we have square roots of negative numbers. Then how can we define $i$ by using the operation $x \mapsto x^2$ on $i$ itself? Surely we need to introduce $i$ before we have operations on $i$. Define a number by extending an operation to a number that already exists, or one that doesn't? (3/4)

Comment: Anyway, none of this matters because talking about "defining $i$" only makes sense in a context where we'd define $0, 1, +, \times$ etc, and that would probably be set theory where we'd define $i = (0,1)$. (4/4)

Comment: @Blrb We could probably discuss this for days and still not agree; I don't think any of its is going to be able to convince the other. However, I want to mention that in my book (see, for instance, field theory), $i^2=-1$ _is_ the actual definition of $i$. Or, rather, $\Bbb C$ is defined as a set of equivalence classes on the set of polynomials in one variable with real coefficients, where we call the variable $i$, and where $i^2$ is in the same equivalence class as $-1$. Also, you can define the square root for complex numbers the way you do, but then you do lose $\sqrt a\sqrt b=\sqrt{ab}$.

Comment: You can, of course, say "but it's valid in some specific cases, like if both of the numbers are real, and only one is negative", but to me it seems like a real hassle to keep all the special cases straight, and if you're someone just learning complex numbers, it's _bound_ to introduce errors. Therefore I choose to stay away from it.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers confirm that your step is okay, I'd like to address *why* it is okay.

Recall that $\sqrt y$ is defined to be the unique non-negative number $a$ such that $a^2 = a\cdot a = y$. If also $b = \sqrt z$, then

$$(ab)^2 = abab = aabb = a^2b^2 = yz$$

So $ab$ is a non-negative number whose square is $yz$. I.e., $$\sqrt{yz} = \sqrt y \sqrt z$$

Answer (score 0):

it is $$\sqrt{(1-(1-2x))(1-2x)}=\sqrt{1-2x-(1-2x)^2}=\sqrt{1-2x-1+4x-4x^2}=\sqrt{2x-4x^2}=\sqrt{2x(1-2x)}$$
it must be $$0\le x\le \frac{1}{2}$$